# how to find every file in my repo that has a specific word in the last line?

Tags: bash, find, tail

In other words, how to combine tail and find/grep command in bash.
I want to find all the files(including the files in subdirectories) in my repo have a specific word in the last line, say FIX in the last line. I tried `grep -Rl "FIX"` to display all the files containing "FIX", but I don't know how to combine the tail command in it. Anyone can help??

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Run `tail` on all the files at once and then grep the output for `FIX`. Since `tail` prepends each line with the corresponding file name when given multiple file names, that's all you have to do.

```
find -type f -exec tail -n1 {} + | grep FIX
```

Or use `**` to find all files and subdirectories, then run `tail` on each of them one at a time:

```
shopt -s globstar
for file in **; do
    [[ -f $file ]] && tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIX && echo "$file"
done
```

Or use `find` to find all matches and pipe it to a `while read` loop:

```
find -type f -print0 | while IFS= read -rd '' file; do
    tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIX && echo "$file"
done
```

Or do the same thing but with `-exec +` and an explicit sub-shell:

```
find -type f -exec sh -c 'for file; do tail -n1 "$file" | grep -q FIX && echo "$file"; done' sh {} +
```

Comment: `for file; do ..... done` or you can remove the `;`  just `for file do ..... done`

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if the last line matches a pattern, use `sed` and restrict the match to the last line with `$`.  `sed` doesn't easily give a return value or do pretty printing of the filename like `grep`, but it gets the job done.

```
find . -exec sh -c "sed -n '$ { /FIX/p; }' {} | grep -q . " \; -print
```

Here, we use `-n` to suppress printing, and then print (with `/p`) only when the last line matches the pattern `/FIX/`.  The output is piped to grep to get a return value that `find` uses to decide whether or not to `-print` the name.

Or, you can avoid using grep for the return by doing something like:

```
find . -exec awk 'END{ exit ! match($0, "FIX")}' {} \; -print
```